# send multiple text from bluetooth using outputStream android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to send multiple texts using output stream.

for example:

editText1 send 'banana', editText2 send 'corn', editText3 send 'bird' at the same time.

do you have any idea how to do it? and please give me some example because I always get confused, I'm new in the android studio.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options. But simple way is to send JSONObject. like,

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("et1","banana");
obj.put("et2","corn");
obj.put("et3","bird");
```

and you can use this Json as String. Like,

```
obj.toString();
```

Comment: can i use rfcomm when i send it via bluetooth? won't it cause problem? @ABK